# angular 4 dropdown filter sibling component with lifecycle hook

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have been going through stack overflow and read some of the other responses for sibling communication with components.  I feel this problem is a little different as I am also trying to include a lifecycle hook into the matter.  Not sure how to improve my code or rethink my problem.

I am currently using **ngbootstrap's** dropdown component and have a table as another component.

The table component and dropdown component currently sit as siblings in my component tree.

I decided that to use a shared service to maintain communication between the components and share my current dropdown with my table so that I can filter through the table for the desired values.

For my shared service I am utilizing rxjs's **BehaviorSubject** and creating a default message that I can change via the **changeMessage()**

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("default message");
    currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

    constructor() {}

    changeMessage(message: string) {
        this.messageSource.next(message);
    }
}
```

In my sibling component that houses my dropdown I declared the sharedService in the constructor and am subscribing to the value.

## Sibling 1 dropdown

```
private dataService: DataService

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.currentMessage
        .subscribe(message => this.message = message);
}
```

Below I added a click handler to the dropdown.  I am using the **(click)** event to pass my argument to a function that will allow me to change the default message and share it with the sibling component housing my table data.

```
 <option
    class="dropdown-item"
    *ngFor="let fac of facilities" 
    (click)="onFacilityChange(fac)">
    {{fac.facility}}
 </option>
```

Here is the method that I am changing the message from the shared service.  Right now I am getting the correct message on each component once the dropdown value is selected

```
 onFacilityChange(facilty) {
    let selectedValue = facilty;
    this.dataService.changeMessage(facilty);
}
```

## Sibling 2 table

#### Template

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let order of orders" (click)="handleGridItemClicked(order)">
        <td data-th="Patient">
            <span class="input">
                <span>
                    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Username"
                        (click)="handleOrderItemChecked($event,order)"
                        [checked]="isSelected">
                </span>
                <span>{{order?.patient?.patientName}}</span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td data-th="Facility">{{order?.patient?.facility}}</td>       
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I initialized the shared value in a constructor and subscribed to it inside of **ngOnInit**.

```
  private dataService: DataService

  this.dataService.currentMessage
            .subscribe(message => this.message = message);
```

## Problem

My problem gets more difficult as I try to filter the table data with the subscribed message

```
filterPatientsByType() {
    let test = this.orders.filter(order => order.patient.facility.includes(this.message.facility));
}
```

All of my table data is inside of **this.orders**.  I created the filter to remove all facilities that don't include match the message.  I could not think of a proper lifecycle hook to use. Or if there is a better way to solve this problem.

I ended up using **ngDoCheck()**. I am not a fan of this as it is constantly running across.  I wanted to do **ngOnChange()** but I do not have defined inputs.  Also the although **filterByTypes ** is filtering down my array correctly I am not seeing the changes on my table.

```
ngDoCheck() {
    this.filterPatientsByType();
}
```

Comment: can you post template of `Sibling 2 table`?

Comment: for the second call onwards you should be using `messageSource.next()` and make the variable to be public

Comment: @Pengyy yes.  I was a little worried that it would take too much space.

Comment: @Winnemucca just the part of how you show the filtered data.

Comment: @Winnemucca I think you should invoke `filterPatientsByType` at `this.dataService.currentMessage
            .subscribe` in order to filter automatically. Also, you should use another public variable to keep the filtered result and show with the filtered result at template.

Comment: @Winnemucca another way is invoke the `filterPatientsByType` function at template like `*ngFor="let order of filterPatientsByType()"` and return the filtered result at function `filterPatientsByType`

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I am working on invoking  filterPatientsByType in the subscribe right now.  Did not think of that.  I am thinking filterPatientsByType would serve as the third argument? ex: nextCallback,
  errorCallback,
  completeCallback

Comment: @Winnemucca I didn't get what you means. Just invoke `filterPatientsByType` after `this.message = message;`

Comment: Alright.  long night I see what you mean.  That definitely helped me get rid of the doCheck() lifecycle hook.  I will look at additional points you made. Thanks!